# Software that show pressed keyboard to desktop

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, screencast

I've found key-mon. But it's very limited is there any program like key-mon that shows keysrokes every time I type to screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `screenkey`. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install screenkey` or with the software center. Then open it and try any shortcut.